# Issue in a function that converts a string into a valid date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been using this function for last few years that converts an input string into a valid date in decided format.

```
select FN_RETURN_VALID_DATE('20200228005815354241') from dual;
```

The above query will return, 28-02-2002 00:58:15

However starting 29/02/2020, if the input string to the function changes to '202002**29**005947354241', it returns a null! I am not sure if this something related to leap year but not able to figure it out yet.

The function definition is,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "FN_RETURN_VALID_DATE" ( v_STR IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN 
DATE
IS
BEGIN
RETURN TO_DATE
( 
    substr(v_STR, 7, 2) || '-' || 
    substr(v_STR, 5, 2) || '-' ||  
    substr(v_STR, 2, 2) || ' ' ||
    substr(v_STR, 9, 2) || ':' || 
    substr(v_STR, 11, 2) || ':' || 
    substr(v_STR, 13, 2), 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN NULL;
END;
```

I have checked that there is no error as when I checked I received this message "ORA-0000: normal, successful completion".
Please let me know what could be the issue.

Regards,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be simply done in pure SQL:

```
with data as(
    select '20200229005947354241' input_dt from dual
)
select input_dt, 
       to_char(
           to_date(
               substr(input_dt, 1, 14), 
               'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
          'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt 
from data;

INPUT_DT             DT                 
-------------------- -------------------
20200229005947354241 29-02-2020 00:59:47
```

Another thing in your code which is really dangerous:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN NULL;
```

It’s a bug waiting for its chance to break the atomicity of a procedural call. You are hiding the error in your code. Please see [WHEN OTHERS – A bug](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: But actually, I tested it separately for printing any error message (by commenting RETURN NULL statement) and as mentioned in my question it returned ORA-0000: normal, successful completion, which means no error. Your version is much better than mine and I will remember not to use RETURN NULL when I am expecting any error message. Thanks once again.

Comment: @sachinvaidya Always remember, a when others is almost always a BUG unless it is immediately followed by a RAISE. Go through my blog link which will provide you more insights. Also, SQL is much faster than PL/SQL, you could avoid the unnecessary context switching.

Comment: Although the query is working I would prefer `to_date(substr(input_dt, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')` which should be clearer to the questioner.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks. though I did use the way you have mentioned, I really appreciate you for taking the time to mention this detail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with year format, if you are using 2 digit year format "RR" will give you current century. However it is best is to use 4 digit Year format to avoid confusion

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "FN_CHK_VALID_DATE" ( v_STR IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN 
DATE
IS
BEGIN
RETURN TO_DATE
( 
    substr(v_STR, 7, 2) || '-' || 
    substr(v_STR, 5, 2) || '-' ||  
    substr(v_STR, 0, 4) || ' ' ||
    substr(v_STR, 9, 2) || ':' || 
    substr(v_STR, 11, 2) || ':' || 
    substr(v_STR, 13, 2), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN NULL;
END;
```